# Python - Trying to extract lines containing a key word from multiple files in a directory

Tags: python, file, directory, extract

I am trying to build a script which can look for all files in a certain folder, and pull any lines of text that contain a key word or phrase.

Very new to python, and not really understanding how to piece together multiple suggestions from others I have seen.

```
import re
from glob import glob

search = []
linenum = 0
pattern = re.compile("Dawg", re.IGNORECASE)  # Compile a case-insensitive regex
path = 'C:\\Users\\Username\\Downloads\Testdataextraction\\Throw it in\\Audit_2022.log'
filenames = glob('*.log')
print(f"\n{filenames}")
with open (path, 'rt') as myfile:    
    for line in myfile:
        linenum += 1
        if pattern.search(line) != None:      # If a match is found 
            search.append((linenum, line.rstrip('\n')))
for x in search:                            # Iterate over the list of tuples
    print("\nLine " + str(x[0]) + ": " + x[1])
```

This does everything exactly how I want it, except can only see one file at a time.
My issue arises when I try deleting 'Audit_2022.log' from the end of the path = line.

Python says *"PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\Username\Downloads\Testdataextraction\Throw it in'"*. I assume this is because it's looking at a directory and not a file, but how can I get it to read multiple files?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Wouldn't you also want to print the name of the file(s) where the pattern was observed?

Comment: I would, I just don't know how to do that either!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you also need to show the filename(s) you could do this:

```
import re
from glob import glob
import os
p = re.compile('Dawg', re.IGNORECASE)
path = r'C:\Users\Username\Downloads\Testdataextraction\Throw it in'
for file in glob(os.path.join(path, '*.log')):
    with open(file) as logfile:
        for i, line in enumerate(map(str.strip, logfile), 1):
            if p.search(line) is not None:
                print(f'File={file}, Line={i}, Data={line}')
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting that Exception is because `open` needs a filename, and if you give it just a path, it doesn't really know what to do. A minimal example could be:

```
path = 'C:\\Users\\Username\\Downloads\Testdataextraction\\Throw it in\\Audit_2022.log'
with open (path, 'rt') as f:
  pass
```

If the file exists, this should run fine, but if you change it to:

```
path = 'C:\\Users\\Username\\Downloads\Testdataextraction\\Throw it in'
with open (path, 'rt') as f:
  pass
```

Then this will throw the exception.

I suspect what you're trying to do is glob through all log files in `path` and try each one, so something like:

```
import os
path = 'C:\\Users\\Username\\Downloads\Testdataextraction\\Throw it in'
filenames = glob(os.path.join(path, '*.log'))   
print(f"\n{filenames}")
for filename in filenames:
  with open (filename, 'rt') as myfile:
  ...
```

Comment: I just tried this, and the output is giving me this error:
filenames = glob('*.log', root_dir=path)

TypeError: glob() got an unexpected keyword argument 'root_dir'

Comment: Sorry, root_dir wasn't added until Python 3.10.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.listdir()` to get all files in a directory, then nest your opening loop for each `file` in the directory:

```
import os

folder = 'C:\\Users\\Username\\Downloads\Testdataextraction\\Throw it in'

for file in glob(os.path.join(folder, '*.log')):
    with open(file, 'rt') as myfile:
        for line in myfile:
            linenum += 1
            if pattern.match(line): # If a match is found
                search.append((linenum, line.rstrip('\n')))
```

> See [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) for a better path joining alternative

Comment: Thanks for the response Freddy. I tried the above, and got this:

```for file in glob('*.log', os.listdir(folder)):

TypeError: glob() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given```

Comment: @GitGoodSnek, I had the arguments the wrong way around, try the new example please

Comment: Gave it another crack
`for file in glob(os.listdir(folder), '*.log'):

TypeError: glob() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Comment: @GitGoodSnek, edited again - does it work with new exmaple?

Comment: It does sometimes. It pay pull half of the lines with the key word in it. But not the other half for some reason.

Comment: @GitGoodSnek, are you searching sub-folders?, what's the output of `print(glob(os.path.join(folder, '*.log')))`? Ensure that it has found all files

Comment: @GitGoodSnek, i've changed the regex slightly, see if that helps

Comment: It's finding all 3 test files. But it's only grabbing 1 line from each file. Instead of the 2 I am expecting it to grab

Comment: It didn't find any lines in the files with the new regex

Comment: @GitGoodSnek Could you add the lines you are trying to match (with explanation) to your question please?